# Google Document AI Form Parser is not returning entities for all pages

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, cloud-document-ai

I am trying the Google Document AI with a standard Form Parser. I processed a 60 pages PDF file and the OCR result returned `entities` for a first few pages and the rest of the pages do not include the `entities` in response. I couldn't find a documentation about this field but is this optimistic field?

Is there any way to enforce to have this field in all the response?

If not, is there any way to identify what *kind* of pages would likely to have this field in response vs not? i.e. how the page should look like to make the `entities` detection to run.

```py
gcs_docs = [
    documentai.GcsDocument(
        gcs_uri=input_file, 
        mime_type='application/pdf'
    )
]   

gcs_documents = documentai.GcsDocuments(documents=gcs_docs)
input_config = documentai.BatchDocumentsInputConfig(gcs_documents=gcs_documents)

gcs_output_config = documentai.DocumentOutputConfig.GcsOutputConfig(
    gcs_uri=output_file, 
    field_mask="text,entities,pages.pageNumber,pages.formFields",
    sharding_config={"pages_per_shard": 1, "pages_overlap": 0}
)
```

Comment: As long as I know, the page limit is 15, Emma.

Comment: interesting.  I will try splitting and see.  Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It seems the limit is 5 based on what I tested.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [article](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/processors-list#processor_form-parser) Form parser can detect 11 generic Entities. Are the files are images converted to PDF? The api might be having trouble detecting some entites due to image quality etc,

Can try different versions of the API just to see what is stable for your use case? See version management [here](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/manage-processor-versions). (If persist I would recommend filing a support case about this to help possible improvement of entity detection of the processor)

Comment: I am not too concerned about the quality of the detection.  If it doesn't detect anything I still expect `entities` to be in response with empty array or null.  Though what I am seeing is when I pass more than 5 pages pdf to batch process, it only returns `entities` key for the first 5 jsons. When I split the pdf into 5 pages pdf, I always see `entities` in response.   the doc says max 15 pages, though, I was only successful with max 5 pages.